# Hashes with Vue Router

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-router

I have a page with multiple anchor tags:

```
<a name="my-link"></a>
```

I am then trying to generate links to these locations on the right hand side of the page like so:

```
<li v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
  <router-link :to="{hash:item.hash}">{{item.text}}</router-link>
</li>
```

However, whenever I do so clicking on the link takes me to the top of the page. I did have the code like this which did work:

```
<li v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
  <a href="{hash:item.hash}">{{item.text}}</a>
</li>
```

Both ways, when reloading the page or clicking on a link generated from the above two templates are not highlighting the main top navbar item. I am using this css:

```
nav.top > ul > li > a:hover,
nav.top > ul > li > a.router-link-exact-active.router-link-active {
  background: #ee2012;
}
```

What is the proper way to integrate hashes `/my-route#my-hash` using vue and vue router?

Comment: Where is this `{hash:}` thing coming from?

Comment: it is an array `this.items = Array.from(main.querySelectorAll("h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6")).map(...);` and then `data() {
    return {
      items: []
    }
  }`